# Google Calendar colorize weekends in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm currently using the following to colorize weekends in Google Calendar in Firefox (week-view):

```
@-moz-document url-prefix("https://www.google.com/calendar/") {  td.tg-weekend {
    background-color: #Ffd4d4;} }
```

But when the day is a weekend, it shows up in the normal bluish color instead of the reddish color. Is it possible to keep the color of the current day red if the current day is a weekend (there is a CSS element called `tg-col-today`, but I don't know how to use that to check if the **today** column is the same as a **weekend** column)

Comment: Does adding `!important` to the rule work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `td.tg-weekend` with `td.tg-weekend, td.tg-weekend .tg-today`

Comment: Woohoo! Perfect! Why does this work? Also, I'm using the Hide Morning and Night Lab, and [this](http://i.imgur.com/Q48rS.png) is what it looks like. Is there a way to fix that? (The white part is the hidden part. Using the code I originally had, neither weekend's hidden part was colored. I want both to be colored) Again, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that fixed it! It works because you're overriding the background color of the div that has the "tg-today" class, but only if it's within `td.tg-weekend`. As for your other problem, I think you can change the color of that element using the `.cgd-gutter-bg-top` selector, but I'm not sure if you can do that for just the weekend.

Comment: Nice. So why doesn't `td.tg-weekend .cgd-gutter-bg-top` work? Is it because `.cgd-gutter-bg-top` is a single element?

Comment: `.cgd-gutter-bg-top` isn't a child of `td.tg-weekend`

Comment: `.tg-today` is a child of `td.tg-weekend`